# Redirect secure URL with javascript without breaking the back button

Tags: javascript, redirect, https, popup, parent

I have a popup generated from a parent jsp page. The popup contains a button which on click, closes the popup and redirects the parent page in the following manner:

```
self.close();
opener.location = "<%= url %>";
```

My problem manifests only on IE8 and I identified the issue as coming from the fact that my popup is a `https:\\` (secure) page while the parent is (unsecure) `http:\\`.

IE8 happens to open the page redirected inside the popup instead of closing the popup and redirecting the parent.

Any solutions that don't include making the parent `https:\\` as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try window.parent instead of window.opener?

Comment: You seem to describe about 3 seperate issues.  Can you be more specific about eacH?

Comment: @LastCoder yes, same thing happends with window.parent.

Comment: @Wug, I want to redirect parent from popup without any IE8 browser issues and without setting the popup unsecure or the parent secure.